# Why am I seeing about a 50V drop at Load Line into a light fixture box?

Tags: electrical, wiring, voltage

Working on a bathroom renovation, moving junction box (JB) that doubles as light fixture (to be centered), there is a 4-wire cable which receives power from another line in that JB. The neutral wire from this 4-wire cable is connected to all other neutrals, no issue, and the red wire is carrying power out (i.e. Black is not connected to anything at this point).

The cable is fed around the wall and the power from this red wire supplies power into a 3-switch box. I've installed new switches and a timer here connecting all lines properly and grounding as required. The Black wire from the aforementioned 4-wire cable is now connected as the LOAD from the switch powering the vanity light (this was the wiring configuration beforehand, I changed nothing).

The Black cable is of course present in the original JB and when turning on the switch to supply power I am seeing a loss of 50V (only 70V on my meter) in this Black load wire.. Is the reason for such a loss the fact that I'm effectively missing a neutral wire? I.e. in a typical configuration the LINE and LOAD are separate cables each with their own neutral, and all connected.

What is the correct solution for this wiring issue? Is another neutral line required to ensure no voltage drop? Previous lighting here included two older pot-lights which seemed to have been operating fine, but a noticeable humming was present, this could explain that noise.

I hope I've explained this decently well? I can upload images if it will help.
Thanks!!

NOTE: image #1 shows junction box/fixture box with 3 lines visible coming in, the 4th line is coming in directly from behind in the middle, THIS IS THE 4-WIRE Cable. The red wire connected to the yellow nut brings power to the switch box (image #2). Both switches and timer pigtail to that Line. They each then provide power through their respective red lines to their loads. Switch on the right is giving power to the black wire (of the 4-wire cable.. see back upper right corner). That black line is visible at the junction box as the single lonesome wire with an orange cap.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R4LKP.jpg)[image]

Comment: You cannot do without a neutral at each light. If you are measuring only 70 V (across a load) I would say that you have wired two lights in SERIES and are thereby dividing the 120 V between two loads. Each load must be connected with 120 V line power AND a neutral which is at 0 V.

Comment: Hi Jim, the switch isn’t powering any lights at the moment (it will become a vanity light).. by lights do you mean the two switches in my switch box in that case? Currently it is only the switch that, once turned ON, I’m only seeing 70V at the line in the JB. Again, this black wire is part of that 4-wire cable whereby the red cable feeds power from the JB to the switch box.

Answer (score 0):

Forget about it.  That tangle of colors is totally unmaintainable.  You need to get that organized, or you'll confuse yourself with every step you take.

My best recommendation for boxes like this is to get a 5-pack of multi-color electrical tape, and re-mark wires as needed so their *function* becomes clear.  Code requires neutral be white.  (but a native white wire in a cable can be re-tasked for a hot if re-marked, but of course nobody ever remarks them lol, so you never know).

Beyond that, there are *commonly used conventions*:

- Black for always-hot
- Red for switched-hot #1
- Blue for switched-hot #2
- Yellow for switched-hot #3.

Think as you mark. Check your work.  You should be able to make short work of that box.

---

Another tool that can be very helpful is a 2-wire extension cord with the plug lopped off and thrown away.  This gives you a socket on one end and 2 loose wires on the other.  Mark it with tape so the neutral wire is white and the hot wire is black.  (neutral = wider blade = ribbed side of cord).

Whenever you are looking at a wire that you think is always-hot, or think is switched-hot... you can confirm that by splicing in the loose wires of the extension cord, and plug something in.   I suggest a 3-socket extension cord, so you can stick a voltmeter in one of the other sockets.

For instance if plugging in a light makes another light illuminate dimly, then those aren't hot and neutral lol.

Comment: Thank you for the recommendations, the extension cord I'll definitely get one prepared for all future projects (including this one!).. oh the fun of purchasing an older home, you never know what you'll find! I did ensure the connections in this switch box are accurate. I.e. all switch black connected to line hot (which is black pigtails), top right corner is the line in (red) which is the power to this box; issue is the right hand switch to load (now black wire in upper right) going back to the JB - JB pic is a link above the other image, not sure how that happened. Colour tape is next!

Comment: Could this be a switch loop that I'm dealing with?